# how to set focus on Bitmap Field,Blue color is not visible,blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-storm

i am using a bitmap field that contains a small image.

when focus comes on that image then blue color of the focus does not appears,how can i set the focus width and height

my code::

```
contract_image_field = new BitmapField(contract_image,Field.FOCUSABLE)
 {
       public void getFocusRect(XYRect rect) 
      {
       rect.width=0;
       rect.height=0;
       //super.getFocusRect(rect);
      }
       protected void onFocus(int direction) 
       {
        myScreen.this.invalidate();
      super.onFocus(direction);
     }
       protected void onUnfocus() 
       {
        myScreen.this.invalidate();
      super.onUnfocus();
     }
      };
      contract_image_field.setBitmap(contract_image);
```

this is the way how i work with image field,

though my image is clickable but i cant see that blue color(i want that please help!!!)

changing values of width and height in getFocusRect does not even solves the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually focus is there but you can't see because focus region is the same as the field's entire extent. if you want to see focus rect increase the field extent.

```
BitmapField  bitmapField = new BitmapField(bitmap,Field.FOCUSABLE){
            protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                setExtent(bitmap.getWidth()+10, bitmap.getHeight()+10);
            }

        };
```

Comment: Thank u so much Vivart for solving my problem

Comment: This will only put the blue focusing area in right side and down side of the bitmap, but not on left side and top side. So, I think a better solution is to use setSpace in the drawFocus method, I'll post the code for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can also avoid increasing the field extent; 
using the following code:

```
BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(bitmap, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)
{
     protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
     {
          setSpace(5, 5);
          super.drawFocus(graphics, on);
     }       
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ashraf's suggestion is correct, only I would try to avoid setting the 'space' on every drawFocus call.

just call [setSpace(int, int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html#setSpace%28int,%20int%29) member once on the bitmapField in question.